# Accessing an object's methods, from an object created by another object

Tags: java, class, object, subclass

I have a program reading from two files, one file is used for creating accounts, the other is used for referencing a thing related to each account and provides values for calculating a cost.

Firstly, the first file...

- Creates an *Account* (either Domestic or Commercial)

  - If Domestic, assigns a read MeterNumber to the account
  - If Commercial, creates an array of Meter objects

    - Each meter has a MeterNumber and can have any number of three types of *Tariff* (Peak, OffPeak, Custom)

      - creates an appropriate *Tariff*
      - **Each tariff has a cost(kWh) function that returns a cost**

The second file then, has a list of meter numbers, the tariff being read, and how many kWh were read. Each meter number can appear many times under different tariff types.

My problem then becomes referencing a specific meter, with its tariff type, and a kWh value to be calculated and returning the total cost associated to each meter

I've been working on the basis in the Main class:

- Load in the second file (meter readings) and store them somehow
- Load in the first file and calculate the amount payable to each account relative to the readings by accessing ?? Account.**MeterNumber[x].*SOMETHING*.Tariff[y]**.cost(v) ??.

  Where x is the MeterNumber being referenced, y is the Tariff being read and v is the kWh value to calculate and the output to contribute to the total payable for that account
- Loop through all accounts, and then print a list of AccountNumbers with their total payable amount

The problem comes when trying to somehow call the cost() function, I don't know how to access it at all from the way it is created, and costing for different tariff types due to any number and types of tariffs being associated to a Meter, each tariff in the array of Tarrifs for each meter is of an unknown tariff type.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Snippets:

Account, Main invokes Account.load()

```
public static Account load(Scanner sc) {
      if (sc.hasNextLine()) {
         AccountNumber accountNumber = AccountNumber.fromString(sc.nextLine());
         String kind = sc.next();
         sc.nextLine();
         
         if (kind.equals("D")) {
            return new DomesticAccount(sc, accountNumber);
         } else {
            return new CommercialAccount(sc, accountNumber);
         }
      } else {
         return null;
      }
   }
```

CommercialAccount, DomesticAccount is the same, but stores only a MeterNumber, not an array of Meters

```
public class CommercialAccount extends Account {

   private Meter[] meters;

   public CommercialAccount(Scanner sc, AccountNumber accountNumber) {
      this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
      int n = sc.nextInt();
      sc.nextLine();
      meters = new Meter[n];
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         meters[i] = Meter.load(sc);
      }
   }
   

   public MeterNumber[] getMeterNumbers() {
      MeterNumber[] ms = new MeterNumber[meters.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < meters.length; i++) {
         ms[i] = meters[i].getMeterNumber();
      }
      return ms;
   }
}
```

Meter

```
public class Meter {

   private MeterNumber meterNumber;
   
   private Tariff[] tariffs;
   
   public Meter(MeterNumber meterNumber, Tariff[] tariffs) {
      this.meterNumber = meterNumber;
      this.tariffs = tariffs;
   }
  
   public static Meter load(Scanner sc) {
      MeterNumber meterNumber = MeterNumber.fromString(sc.nextLine());
      int n = sc.nextInt();
      sc.nextLine();
      Tariff[] tariffs = new Tariff[n];
      String[] tariffTypes = new String[n];
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         String kind = sc.next();
         sc.nextLine();
         if (kind.equals("P")) {
            tariffs[i] = PeakTariff.PEAK_TARIFF;
            tariffTypes[i] = "P";
         } else if (kind.equals("O")) {
            tariffs[i] = OffPeakTariff.OFF_PEAK_TARIFF;
            tariffTypes[i] = "O";
         } else {
            tariffs[i] = ContractedTariff.load(sc);
            tariffTypes[i] = "S";
         }
      }
      return new Meter(meterNumber, tariffs);
   }
   
   public MeterNumber getMeterNumber() {
      return meterNumber;
   }
   

}
```

Tariff

```
public abstract class Tariff {

   public abstract double cost(double kWh);

}
```

ContractedTariff

```
public class ContractedTariff extends Tariff {
   
   private double r1, r2, r3, // rates in $/kWh
                  t1, t2;     // thresholds in kWh
   
   public static ContractedTariff load(Scanner sc) {
      ContractedTariff ct = new ContractedTariff(sc.nextDouble(), sc.nextDouble(),
         sc.nextDouble(), sc.nextDouble(), sc.nextDouble());
      sc.nextLine();
      return ct;
   }
   
   public double cost(double kWh) {
      return 666.0; // placeholder
   }

}
```

OffPeakTariff, PeakTariff is essentially identical.

```
public class OffPeakTariff extends Tariff {
   
   public static final double RATE = 0.1543; // $/kWh
   
   // only one instance is required.
   public static final OffPeakTariff OFF_PEAK_TARIFF = new OffPeakTariff();
   
   public double cost(double kWh) {
      return 666.0;  // placeholder
   }   

}
```

Comment: Please give some code, then it is easier to help.

Comment: No worries, I have added all of the code that I think it necessary to work this out, sorry if I'm breaking a whole bunch of rules on how to make a question, kind-of new here

Comment: I don't understand your problem, starting from an account, iterates its "Meter", iterate their "Tariff", call `cost` for each one and sum; Is that the question?

Comment: This is for an assignment, so order of operation and how it is achieved is important.

Main creates Accounts which create meters which create tariffs.
Main also needs to read an Account after creation, and go through its meters referencing kWh usage levels to each tariff of each meter, Main then summing the cost outcomes of all of the Account's meters and printing a list of account numbers with their cost to pay.
The only issue I'm really having is how do I call the cost() function from Main on each of the Account's Meter's Tariffs?
Thanks